# Why true/true is 1, true/false is Infinity, false/true is 0 and false/false is NaN?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am excited to find the following Javascript behavior:

```
$ node
> false/true
0
> false/false
NaN
> false/true
0
> true/true
1
> true/false
Infinity
```

Why is this happening?

---

My first approach is that Javascript converts `false` to `0` and `true` to `1`.

Is this correct? A reference from the documentation would be great.

Comment: check this http://bolinfest.com/javascript/misunderstood.html

Comment: Check out the explanation of toNumber here : http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right, the `ToNumber` abstract operation converts `true` to `1` and `false` to positive `0`.

The [specification](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) says:

> *Boolean*
>
> The result is **1** if the argument is **true**. The result is **+0** if the
>   argument is **false**.

Answer (score 0):

```
> 0/0
NaN
> 1/0
Infinity
> 0/1
0
> 1/1
1
```

They are all converted to numbers.

Comment: Can you add a reference from the documentation...?